# Extract particular text data from string

Tags: r, regex, nlp

I have a sample text like "0 zacapa ambar 40% 1l". I would require help to extract 2 different parts of this text.
Output:
1) zacapa ambar
2) 40% 1l

Example:

```
1 smirnoff espresso twist 10l
1 captain morgan black spiced 10l
1 bulleit 95 rye 10l
```

So I would like to do some fuzzy matching only for string and looking forward to extract details in 2 part.

Comment: What is the logic of the extraction? Please put additional examples in your question (not in comments), i.e. edit your question: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57919736/edit

Comment: Ex:0942 baileys vanilla cinnamon 100cl 17% Output:baileys vanilla cinnamon and 100cl 17%

Comment: Treat (1 smirnoff espresso twist 10) as one observation
Output: smirnoff espresso twist and 10 as separate output.So would require two different output to store the value
Please levae it fuzzy match for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your input is

```
x <- c("1 smirnoff espresso twist 10l", "1 captain morgan black spiced 10l", 
        "1 bulleit 95 rye 10l", "baileys irish cr 17% 100cl")
```

You can get two parts by using

```
part1 <- sub("\\d?\\s(.*?)\\s\\d+.*", "\\1", x)
part2 <- sub("\\d?.*\\s.*(\\d+.*?)", "\\1", x)

part1
#[1] "smirnoff espresso twist"     "captain morgan black spiced" "bulleit"        
#[4] "baileysirish cr"  

part2
#[1] "10l"        "10l"        "95 rye 10l" "17% 100cl"
```

where `part1` is ignoring the first number and extracting all the characters until the next numeric occurs in `x` and `part2` is extracting everything after that.

Comment: Require help to get the pattern for part 1--- start from character and take all the characters until first numeric comes(exclude 1st numeric values)
part 2-where part 1 stops reading(include numeric starts value and rest of string)
Such as 1 smirnoff espresso twist 10l
part 1 - smirnoff espresso twist
part 2 - 10l (l is required it shows unit of measure)
Example 2:1 captain morgan black spiced 10l
part 1 - captain morgan black spiced
part 2 - 10l
Thanks Ronak for efforts

Comment: @Nitish okay..I have updated the answer. Can you check now?

Comment: ...Thank you so much for helping me out.
It address the issue but one question remains here.If in the starting of string,there is no number then this wont work.
Ex:baileys irish cr 17% 100cl.
It returns everything

Comment: So if you can help me out to build a logic match should start with alphabetic value in string.

Comment: @Nitish okay..included that example in the data and updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much Ronak..It works
I was trying one thing if instead of 1 in the beginning ,there are multiple numbers such as 
1890 smirnoff espresso twist 10l......(1345,12,890 different numbers for some strings) how can i modify the existing logic
I really appreciate your efforst Ronak..Thanks for helping